# Compiler requires me to add space before equal sign for default function parameter

Tags: c++

If I write:

```
void compute(char*, char*=0) { // no space before =
}

int main()
{
    compute(0);
}
```

gcc [outputs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849860ffb4eb8b71) :

```
main.cpp:1:25: error: expected ')'
void compute(char*, char*=0) {
                        ^
main.cpp:1:13: note: to match this '('
void compute(char*, char*=0) {
            ^
main.cpp:6:5: error: no matching function for call to 'compute'
    compute(0);
    ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:1:6: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
void compute(char*, char*=0) {
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

if I add space befor `=`: `char* =0` then its all OK.

Is this another example of most vexing parse problem?

Comment: Nope. It's the "[maximum munch](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/The_Scream.jpg) rule".

Comment: `*=` is an existing operator, like `x *= 2` to multiply `x` by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bo Persson has said, `*=` is an existing operator. In this case, `x*=0` would simply multiply x by 0 instead of what you wish to achieve.